# How to average daily data to create a weekly estimate of ERA5 in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, mean

I'm trying to calculate the weekly mean of minimum temperature for the specified period but I can't get what I want. Could you please help out?

```
var pointOfInterest = ee.Geometry.Point(X,Y);

Map.addLayer(pointOfInterest);
Map.centerObject(pointOfInterest);

var startDate = '2015-07-06';
var endDate = '2020-07-05';

var temperatureData = ee.ImageCollection('ECMWF/ERA5/DAILY')
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .select(['minimum_2m_air_temperature'])
  .filterBounds(pointOfInterest);

var computeWeeklyMean = function(image) {
  var date = image.get('system:time_start');
  var weeklyMean = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: pointOfInterest,
    scale: 10000, // Adjust as needed
    bestEffort: true,
  }).get('minimum_2m_air_temperature');
  return ee.Feature(pointOfInterest, {
    'system:time_start': date,
    'minimum_2m_air_temperature': weeklyMean,
  });
};

var weeklyMeanTemperatures = temperatureData.map(computeWeeklyMean);
var weeklyMeanTable = ee.FeatureCollection(weeklyMeanTemperatures);
print(weeklyMeanTable);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `reduceRegion()`, you're getting the temperature at your point from each image. Then you need to calculate the weekly mean for these temperatures.

```
var temperatures = temperatureData.map(toFeature)
var numberOfWeeks = endDate.difference(startDate, 'weeks')
var weeklyMeanTable = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(0, numberOfWeeks.subtract(1))
    .map(toWeeklyMean)
)
print(weeklyMeanTable)
var chart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(weeklyMeanTable, 'date', 'mean')
print(chart)


function toFeature(image) {
  var date = image.get('system:time_start')
  var weeklyMean = image.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
    geometry: pointOfInterest,
    scale: 10000
  }).get('minimum_2m_air_temperature')
  return ee.Feature(pointOfInterest, {
    'system:time_start': date,
    'minimum_2m_air_temperature': weeklyMean,
  })
}

function toWeeklyMean(weekOffset) {
  var dateRange = startDate
    .advance(ee.Number(weekOffset), 'weeks')
    .getRange('week')
  var mean = temperatures
    .filterDate(dateRange)
    .aggregate_mean('minimum_2m_air_temperature')
  return ee.Feature(pointOfInterest, {
    mean: mean, 
    date: dateRange.start().format('yyyy-MM-dd')
  })  
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/3aae4670306d4227ba134d8aae5f039a

Comment: Dear Daniel, than you very much. it is very nice. I'm quite new to GEE. Do you know how I can convert this temperature in Celcius degree and how can I export the results to my drive as CSV file? Thanks again and have a nice day, Nox

Comment: @nox for that, you have to post as a new question. Before that, if your current problem is solved kindly accept this as answer. You can comment anything related to current answer or question here.